# Jquery scrollTo start animation function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrollto

I have been looking for some time on a solutuion for this and I am pretty sure it's possible. Id like to use my current scrollTo function which sets a link to active wiwhen you scroll to a  but would like to add the ability to start the sections animation when scrolled to and not onb page load. By default there will be 3 animated items per section (header, text, image) just to keep it simple. Each section hs a unique id (home, about, etc)

This is the script i have to animate the scrollTo and set the menu links active. How would i got about adding the start animation function?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (windscroll >= 100) {
$('.navigation').addClass('fixed');
$('.wrap section').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 0) {
        $('.navigation a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('.navigation a').eq(i).addClass('active');
    }
});

} else {
$('.navigation a.active').removeClass('active');
$('.navigation a:first').addClass('active');
}

}).scroll();
```

Comment: have you researched it?

Comment: I have researched it and found that the actual scrollto was in a different part of the javascript. What I was looking to do was create a call to animate each section once the section was scrolledto. So you can see the animation instead of on page load.

Comment: $('.scroller').click(function(){
     var section = $($(this).data("section"));
     var top = section.offset().top;
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: top }, 1000, 'easeInOutQuint', function() { 
     alert("Finished animating");
     // animate the sections header, text, and image
  });
        return false;
    });

Comment: My question was has to animate the child div/sections on scrollto.